# Set alpha for UIView/Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a table view with a label array and a UIView, with a UIImage array

```
var menuItems = ["News", "Programm"]
var currentItem = "News"

var menuImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "news.png")!, UIImage(named: "programm_100.png")!]
```

The text and its color of the label is set by:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
cell.titleLabel.textColor = (menuItems[indexPath.row] == currentItem) ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.grayColor()
```

Now I want the Images to appear a bit grey, too.
I've tried to set it with `cell.titlePicture.alpha`.

How can I set UIView's alpha denericly depending on the current item?

[image: menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `titlePicture` is a `UIImageView`, you can edit the alpha of it directly:

```
cell.titlePicture.alpha = (menuItems[indexPath.row] == currentItem) ? 0.6 : 1.0
```

Tweak the alpha values to your liking.  Example output:

alpha = 1.0:

[image: img1]

alpha = 0.6:

[image: img2]

Comment: yes of course. I just had to wait since there's a bit of a delay. I think about 15 minutes, before you're able to accept. But obviously you allready know that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Extension. Just create a new Swift file and implement this:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage{


    func alpha(value:CGFloat)->UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)

        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        let area = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height);

        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, CGBlendMode.Normal);
        CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, value);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, self.CGImage);

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
}
```

Then apply it when setting your image:

```
UIImage(named: "news.png").alpha(0.5)
```